# How does reciprocal SendMessage-ing between two applications work?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, sendmessage

Suppose I have 2 applications, A and B. Each one of them creates one window in the main thread, and has no other threads.

When the "close" button of the window of application A is pressed, the following happens:

1. Application A receives a `WM_CLOSE` message and handles it like:

   ```
   DestroyWindow(hWnd_A);
   return 0;
   ```
2. On `WM_DESTROY` application A behaves like:

   ```
   SendMessage(hWnd_B, WM_REGISTERED_MSG, 0, 0); //key line!!
   PostQuitMessage(0);
   return 0;
   ```
3. On `WM_REGISTERED_MSG` application B runs:

   ```
   SendMessage(hWnd_A, WM_ANOTHER_REGISTERED_MSG, 0, 0);
   return 0;
   ```
4. On `WM_ANOTHER_REGISTERED_MSG` application A runs:

   ```
   OutputDebugString("Cannot print this");
   return 0;
   ```

And that's it.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx), I read that when a message is sent to a window created by another thread, the calling thread is blocked, and it can only process non-queued messages.

Now, since the above code works and does not hang, I guess that the call to `SendMessage` from application B (point 3) sends a non-queued message to application A's window procedure, which processes it **in the context of application B's main thread**. Indeed, no debug output is displayed with `OutputDebugString` in point 4.

This is also proved by the fact that replacing `SendMessage` with `SendMessageTimeout` with the `SMTO_BLOCK` flag in the `key line` of point 2, makes the whole thing actually block. (See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) of `SendMessage`)

Then, my questions are:

- Actually, are non-queued messages just simple direct calls to the window procedure made by `SendMessage` in process B?
- How does `SendMessage` know when to send queued or non-queued messages?

---

**UPDATE**

Still, I do not understand how does A process `WM_ANOTHER_REGISTERED_MSG`. What I would expect is that when that message is sent, A's thread should be waiting for its call to `SendMessage` to return.

Any insight?

---

**SUGGESTION FOR THE READERS**

I would suggest to read Adrian's answer as an introduction to RbMm's one, which follows the same line of thought, but goes more in detail.

Comment: "*I guess that the call to `SendMessage` from application B (point 3) sends a non-queued message to application A's window procedure, which processes it **in the context of application B's main thread**.*" - that is not true at all. When `SendMessage()` sends a message to a window in another thread, `SendMessage()` blocks the calling thread waiting for the receiving thread processes the message. The message is processed in the context of the receiving thread, not the context of the sending thread.

Comment: Thank you, I will update the question, putting A's `SendMessage` before `DestroyWindow`. I still do not understand how can A process `WM_REGISTERED_MSG` in its own thread, because A's thread should be waiting for its call to 'SendMessage' to return.. shouldn't it?

Comment: See [About Messages and Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx). `A` sends `WM_REGISTERED_MSG` and blocks until `B` processes it. `B` sends `WM_ANOTHER_REGISTERED_MSG` before exiting from `WM_REGISTERED_MSG`. `A`'s blocked `SendMessage()` receives and processes `WM_ANOTHER_REGISTERED_MSG` and then goes back to waiting for `WM_REGISTERED_MSG` to finish being processed. `PostMessage()` posts queued messages, `SendMessage()` sends non-queued messages.

Comment: Michael, please consider the updated code. Does it fix that?

Comment: This question appears to be rather theoretical. What is the use case of this?

Comment: An application that controls the execution of other applications could use the above approach (or a similar one) to notify to the controlled applications to clean up and exit.

Comment: `SendMessage` always send nonqueued messages. described by you behavior is worked well.

Comment: @RbMm : Agreed. Found the bug in my test case and already deleted that comment.

Comment: `//key line!!` is wrong - your first code was correct. you can call `SendMessage` exactly from `WM_DESTROY`

Comment: Well, then I'm going to modify back the question :) Thanks!

Comment: I guess you haven't heard of `PostMessage`.  Makes the question "queued or non-queued" trivially easy -- if `PostMessage` it is queued, if `SendMessage` it is non-queued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the described behavior really work well.

> How does `SendMessage` know when to send queued or non-queued
>   messages?

from [*Nonqueued Messages*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx#nonqueued_messages)

> Some functions that send nonqueued messages are ... [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx)
>   ...

so [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) simply always send nonqueued messages.

and from [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) documentation:

> However, the sending thread will process incoming nonqueued messages
>   while waiting for its message to be processed.

this mean that window procedure can be called inside `SendMessage` call. and process incoming messages sent via `SendMessage` from another thread. how this is implemented ?

when we call `SendMessage` message to another thread window, it enter to kernel mode. kernel mode always remember usermode stack pointer. and we switched to kernel stack. when we return from kernel to user mode - kernel usually return back to point, from where user mode called it and to saved stack. but exist and exceptions. one of this:

```
NTSYSCALLAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
KeUserModeCallback
(
    IN ULONG RoutineIndex,
    IN PVOID Argument,
    IN ULONG ArgumentLength,
    OUT PVOID* Result,
    OUT PULONG ResultLenght
);
```

this is exported but undocumented api. however it all time used by win32k.sys for call window procedure. how this api worked ?

first of all it allocate additional kernel stack frame below current. than it take saved user mode stack pointer and copy some data (arguments) below it. finally we exit from kernel to user mode, but not to point, from where kernel was called but for special ( exported from ntdll.dll) function -

```
void
KiUserCallbackDispatcher
(
    IN ULONG RoutineIndex,
    IN PVOID Argument,
    IN ULONG ArgumentLength
);
```

and stack was **below** stack pointer, from where we enter kernel early.
`KiUserCallbackDispatcher` call `RtlGetCurrentPeb()->KernelCallbackTable[RoutineIndex](Argument, ArgumentLength)` - usually this is some function in user32.dll. this function already call corresponded window procedure. from window procedure we can call kernel back - because `KeUserModeCallback` allocate additional kernel frame - we will be enter to kernel inside this frame and not damage previous. when window procedure return - again special api called

```
__declspec(noreturn)
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
ZwCallbackReturn
(
    IN PVOID Result OPTIONAL,
    IN ULONG ResultLength,
    IN NTSTATUS Status
);
```

this api (if no error) must never return - in kernel side - the allocated kernel frame is de-allocated and we return to previous kernel stack inside `KeUserModeCallback`. so we finally return from point, from where `KeUserModeCallback` was called. then we back to user mode, exactly from point where we call kernel, on same stack.

really how is window procedure is called **inside** call to `GetMessage` ? exactly by this. call flow was:

```
GetMessage...
--- kernel mode ---
KeUserModeCallback...
push additional kernel stack frame
--- user mode --- (stack below point from where GetMessage enter kernel)
KiUserCallbackDispatcher
WindowProc
ZwCallbackReturn
-- kernel mode --
pop kernel stack frame
...KeUserModeCallback
--- user mode ---
...GetMessage
```

exactly the same was with blocking `SendMessage`.

so when *thread_A* send *message_1* to *thread_B* via `SendMessage` - we enter to kernel, signal gui *event_B*, on which *thread_B* waited. and begin wait on gui *event_A* for current thread. if *thread_B* executes message retrieval code (call `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` ) `KeUserModeCallback` called in *thread_B*. as result executed it window procedure. here it call `SendMessage` to send some *message_2* to *thread_A* back. as result we set *event_A* on which *thread_A* wait and begin wait on *event_B*. *thread_A* will be awaken and call `KeUserModeCallback`. it Window procedure will be called with this message. when it return (assume this time we not more call `SendMessage`) we again signal back *event_B* and begin wait on *event_A*. 
now *thread_B* return from `SendMessage` and then return from window procedure - finalize handle original *message_1*. will be *event_A* set. `thread_A` awaken and return from `SendMessage`. call flow will be next:

```
thread_A                        thread_B
----------------------------------------------------
                                GetMessage...
                                wait(event_B)
SendMessage(WM_B)...
set(event_B)
wait(event_A)
                                begin process WM_B...
                                KeUserModeCallback...
                                    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
                                    WindowProc(WM_B)...
                                    SendMessage(WM_A)...
                                    set(event_A)
                                    wait(event_B)
begin process WM_A...
KeUserModeCallback...
    KiUserCallbackDispatcher
    WindowProc(WM_A)...
    ...WindowProc(WM_A)
    ZwCallbackReturn
...KeUserModeCallback
set(event_B)
...end process WM_A
wait(event_A)
                                    ...SendMessage(WM_A)
                                    ...WindowProc(WM_B)
                                    ZwCallbackReturn
                                ...KeUserModeCallback
                                set(event_A)
                                ...end process WM_B
                                wait(event_B)
...SendMessage(WM_B)
                                ...GetMessage
```

also note that when we handle `WM_DESTROY` message - window is still valid and call process incoming messages. we can implement next demo: at first we not need 2 processes. absolute enough single process with 2 threads. and special registered message here not need. why not use say `WM_APP` as test message ?

1. *thread_A* from self `WM_CREATE` create *thread_B* and pass own window handle to it.
2. *thread_B* create self window, but on `WM_CREATE` simply return -1 (for fail create window)
3. *thread_B* from `WM_DESTROY` call `SendMessage(hwnd_A, WM_APP, 0, hwnd_B)` (pass self *hwnd* as *lParam*)
4. *thread_A* got `WM_APP` and call `SendMessage(hwnd_B, WM_APP, 0, 0)`
5. *thread_B* got `WM_APP` (so `WindowProc` was recursively called, on stack bellow `WM_DESTROY`
6. *thread_B* print "Cannot print this" and return self ID to *thread_A*
7. *thread_A* returned from call `SendMessage` and return self ID to *thread_B*
8. *thread_B* returned from call `SendMessage` inside `WM_DESTROY`

---

```
ULONG WINAPI ThreadProc(PVOID hWnd);

struct WNDCTX 
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    HWND hWndSendTo;
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WNDCTX* ctx = reinterpret_cast<WNDCTX*>(GetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_NULL:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_APP:
        DbgPrint("%x:%p>WM_APP:(%p, %p)\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), _AddressOfReturnAddress(), wParam, lParam);

        if (lParam)
        {
            DbgPrint("%x:%p>Send WM_APP(0)\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), _AddressOfReturnAddress());
            LRESULT r = SendMessage((HWND)lParam, WM_APP, 0, 0);
            DbgPrint("%x:%p>SendMessage=%p\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), _AddressOfReturnAddress(), r);
            PostMessage(hWnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            DbgPrint("%x:%p>Cannot print this\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), _AddressOfReturnAddress());
        }

        return GetCurrentThreadId();

    case WM_DESTROY:

        if (HANDLE hThread = ctx->hThread)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }

        if (HWND hWndSendTo = ctx->hWndSendTo)
        {
            DbgPrint("%x:%p>Send WM_APP(%p)\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), _AddressOfReturnAddress(), hWnd);
            LRESULT r = SendMessage(hWndSendTo, WM_APP, 0, (LPARAM)hWnd);
            DbgPrint("%x:%p>SendMessage=%p\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), _AddressOfReturnAddress(), r);
        }
        break;

    case WM_NCCREATE:
        SetLastError(0);

        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, 
            reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams));

        if (GetLastError())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        break;

    case WM_CREATE:

        if (ctx->hWndSendTo)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (ctx->hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc, hWnd, 0, 0))
        {
            break;
        }
        return -1;

    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

static const WNDCLASS wndcls = { 
    0, WindowProc, 0, 0, (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"lpszClassName" 
};

ULONG WINAPI ThreadProc(PVOID hWndSendTo)
{
    WNDCTX ctx = { 0, (HWND)hWndSendTo };

    CreateWindowExW(0, wndcls.lpszClassName, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, &ctx);

    return 0;
}

void DoDemo()
{
    DbgPrint("%x>test begin\n", GetCurrentThreadId());

    if (RegisterClassW(&wndcls))
    {
        WNDCTX ctx = { };

        if (CreateWindowExW(0, wndcls.lpszClassName, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, &ctx))
        {
            MSG msg;

            while (0 < GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }

        UnregisterClassW(wndcls.lpszClassName, (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase);
    }

    DbgPrint("%x>test end\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
}
```

---

i got next output:

```
d94>test begin
6d8:00000008884FEFD8>Send WM_APP(0000000000191BF0)
d94:00000008880FF4F8>WM_APP:(0000000000000000, 0000000000191BF0)
d94:00000008880FF4F8>Send WM_APP(0)
6d8:00000008884FEB88>WM_APP:(0000000000000000, 0000000000000000)
6d8:00000008884FEB88>Cannot print this
d94:00000008880FF4F8>SendMessage=00000000000006D8
6d8:00000008884FEFD8>SendMessage=0000000000000D94
d94>test end
```

most interesting look stack trace of *thread_B* when it recursively called on `WM_APP`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I find this is the most complete answer, and it fixes many holes in my understanding of the underlying behavior of Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

> Still, I do not understand how does A process WM_ANOTHER_REGISTERED_MSG. What I would expect is that when that message is sent, A's thread should be waiting for its call to `SendMessage` to return.

The `SendMessage` in A *is* waiting for the message it sent (from A to B) to complete, but, while it's waiting, it's able to dispatch messages sent from other threads to this thread.

When `SendMessage` is called for a window on the same thread, we think of it like a chain of function calls that eventually leads to the target windowproc and eventually returns to the caller.

But when the message crosses thread boundaries, it's not that simple.  It becomes like a client-server application.  `SendMessage` packages up the message and signals the target thread that it has a message to process.  At that point, it waits.

The target thread eventually (we hope) reaches a yield point where it checks that signal, gets the message and processes it.  The target thread then signals that it's done the work.

The original thread sees the "I'm done!" signal and returns the result value.  To the caller of `SendMessage`, it looks like it was just a function call, but it was actually choreographed to marshal the message over to the other thread and marshal the result back.

Several Windows API calls are "yield points," places that check to see if there's a message being sent to the current thread from another thread.  The most well-known ones are `GetMessage` and `PeekMessage`, but certain types of waits--including the wait inside a `SendMessage`--are also yield points.  It's this yield point that makes it possible for A to respond to the message sent back from B all while waiting for B to finish processing the first message.

Here's part of the call stack for A when it receives the `WM_ANOTHER_REGISTERED_MSG` back from B (step 4):

```
A.exe!MyWnd::OnFromB(unsigned int __formal, unsigned int __formal, long __formal, int & __formal)
A.exe!MyWnd::ProcessWindowMessage(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int uMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam, long & lResult, unsigned long dwMsgMapID)
A.exe!ATL::CWindowImplBaseT<ATL::CWindow,ATL::CWinTraits<114229248,262400> >::WindowProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int uMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam)
atlthunk.dll!AtlThunk_Call(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)
atlthunk.dll!AtlThunk_0x00(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)
user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()
user32.dll!DispatchClientMessage()
user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()
user32.dll!SendMessageW()
A.exe!MyWnd::OnClose(unsigned int __formal, unsigned int __formal, long __formal, int & __formal)
```

You can see the `OnClose` *is* still inside `SendMessageW`, but, nested within that, it's getting the callback message from B and routing that to A's window procedure.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian. That was really helpful.